# how to get last clicked event data in entire javascript scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function my_fun(){
  var data = $(this).data();
  // this is undefined
  console.log(data.crm);
}

$(document).on('click', '#add_image', (function() {
  var data = $(this).data();
  // this works
  console.log(data.crm);
  my_fun();
}));
```

```html
<a class="add_img" href="#" data-crm="1" id="add_image">Add Image</a>
```

Basically I want to access html link set data (i.e. value of dataset crm) in my_fun() without sending parameter to my_fun().

> How to access click events html set data in the entire scope of javascript.
>   javascript.

Comment: just check my answer

Answer (score 0):

There's a limited number of ways to do this. One is to pass arguments to the called function.
Another is to just reference the function, and you'll keep the `this` value

```
function my_fun(){
   var data = $(this).data();
   // this is undefined
   console.log(data.crm);
}

$(document).on('click', '#add_image', my_fun);
```

Lastly, there's `bind`, `apply` or `call`

```
my_fun.bind(this)();
// or
my_fun.call(this);
// or
my_fun.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but in same click event I have to do many more thing. And also what if my_fun also call some another function and there I want to access that data

Comment: then use the same argument signature from the event handler function to call my_fun(), but using the call() method, and prepending _this_ to the arguments. ex: `my_fun(1,2,3);` becomes  `my_fun.call(this, 1,2,3);`

Comment: thanks @dandavis. I don't want to send arguments as i said in my question, because i used number of subsequent function to do thing. So how to gety click event data attribute access in any subsequent function

Comment: @maheshkajale:  then simply use `my_fun.call(this);` instead of `my_fun();` ... one neat way to clone/mask an event handler is using my_fun.apply(this, arguments); which invokes any function as though it were the bound  handler...

Comment: That is last option. and also i need to send this to every subsequent function which i used. That is not useful.

Comment: @maheshkajale - Well, what is useful, the only way to keep the `this` value inside the function is either referencing it in the right place, or using `call`, `apply` or `bind` to set the `this` value, there are no other magic methods to do this. Maybe you should be clearer about what exactly it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @adeneo I totally agree with you. But I exactly need data set of last click event occurred in any subsequent function/functions without passing this to every function or binding all function together etc.

Comment: If there is no way to get that. I will update my logic. And will solve problem by other way.

Answer (score 0):

**[Global variable in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Global_Variables)**

```js
function my_fun() {
  console.log(data.crm);
}

$(document).on('click', '#add_image', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  data = $(this).data();
  console.log(data.crm);
  my_fun();
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="add_img" href="#" data-crm="1" id="add_image">Add Image</a>
```

Comment: Hey Pranav thanks. This is specific solution. Here in your code you have not declared variable data so in my_fun prints global data variable value. actually i want to access that la click events data in any subsequent functions which I use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a context to your function by `call` method:

```
my_fun.call(this);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hju0qgav/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_fun(event){
   var data = $(event.target).data();
   console.log(data.crm);
}

$(document).on('click', '#add_image', my_fun);
```

or

```
  function my_fun(event){
       var data = $(event.target).data();
       console.log(data.crm);
    }

    $(document).on('click', '#add_image', function(e){          
      my_fun(e);
});
```